# ClamAV - automatic signature updates in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: clamav

After installing `clamav` in Ubuntu 16.04, do I have to explicitly schedule a cron job to run `freshclam` periodically? Or do the signatures get updated automatically by `clamav`?

Answer (score 3):

When all necessary packages are installed, the signatures are updated automatically in Ubuntu.
That happens periodically 24 times each day, so every 60 minutes when you do not change this.

Check whether you have the following packages installed :
`clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam`

To do it execute the following command :
`dpkg --get-selections | grep clamav`

Default settings : signature database updates **every hour**
You can change the settings by running these commands :

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon`
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam`